# is there any way to redirect a php page if there are no variables in the url?

Tags: php

I'm trying to do something really simple but I can't figure out a way to do it. Basically I have a PHP page that gets called like

```
file.php?details=100
```

or

```
file.php?details=100&page=2
```

etc.

The problem is ...I want the page to be redirected to index.php when it gets called only as:

```
file.php
```

How would I do that? Basically if there are NO variables in the request, it should redirect to index.php. If there are ANY variables in the request, it should load normally.

Thank you for any advice :)

Comment: You need to do this in `.htaccess` based on the URL and possible structure, but not sure exactly where to point you other than that.

Comment: you can do a `if(!isset($_GET['details'] && other vars){redirect}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering `$page` to be the redirected page:

```
if (empty($_GET)) { header('Location: '.$page); exit; }
```

Comment: Thank you and everyone else. Works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1):

In file.php at the start have:

```
<?php
if (!isset($GET_[`details`]))
{
   header("Location: index.php");
   exit(0);
}

... rest of code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this within the PHP file like this:

```
if(count($_GET) < 1) {
    location('Header: index.php');
}
```

Or in a `.htaccess` file doing something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule page\.php index.php
```

I'm writing the above from memory, I can't guarantee that it works literally. Play around with it. I'd recommend the `.htaccess` solution for performance reasons - it doesn't have to execute any PHP code to redirect.